# How to get the mobile number and work number from iPhone contacts using MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, contacts

How to get the mobile number and work number from iPhone contacts using MonoTouch c#? I used this code,

```
ABMultiValue<String> phoneMV =  person.GetPhones();
String[] phoneval = phoneMV.GetValues();
for(int i = 0; i< phoneval.Length; i++) {
Console.WriteLine(phoneval[i]); 
}
```

But it prints all value of contact numbers. How to get particular attributes from contacts? For example i need mobile and work number, home and work email id like that. I don't want all values. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [ABMultiValue<T>](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.AddressBook.ABMultiValue%601) is a collection of [ABMultiValueEntry<T>](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.AddressBook.ABMultiValueEntry%601) values. The type of phone number (work, home, etc.) is stored in the [ABMultiValueEntry<T>.Label](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=P%3aMonoTouch.AddressBook.ABMultiValueEntry%601.Label) property, which you can compare against e.g. [ABLabel.Work](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=P%3aMonoTouch.AddressBook.ABLabel.Work):

```
IEnumerable<ABMultiValueEntry<string>> workPhoneEntries = person.GetPhones()
        .Where(p => p.Label == ABLabel.Work);
IEnumerable<string> workNumbers = workPhoneEntries.Select(p => p.Value);
```

Comment: How to get the Address from contact? i got all values from contact. But i cant get the Address.

Comment: Addresses are the same-just-different; ABPerson.GetAddresses() returns (effectively) `IEnumerable<ABMultiValueEntry<NSDictionary>>`, similar to ABPerson.GetPhones(), so check `ABMultiValueEntry<NSDictionary>.Label` for the "right" address (work, home, etc.). `ABMultiValueEntry<NSDictionary>.Value` contains the address, where the key is an address-part and the value is the address-value; see: http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aMonoTouch.AddressBook.ABPersonAddressKey